# White to Alpha PaintDotNet Plugin?

Tags: paint.net

I used to have a plugin pack that had an effect called White To Alpha.
It was incredibly useful, but I can't seem to find it on google.
Does anyone know what plugin pack this was?

Comment: Google can't find it? Typing your question title into Google finds it - https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=White+to+Alpha+PaintDotNet+Plugin%3F&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: @Tetsujin
I'm not looking for Color to Alpha. 

Specifically there was one called "White to Alpha" which was part of an even broader plugin pack. The words are exact.